# record feature to my drum Machine

Tags: record

I'm in the process of developing a drum machine application. We have added sound to the buttons and now we would like to add a record and play button but can't seem to figure out how to write the code. We were hoping you might be able to help us. Thanks

Comment: What language, what operating environment, are you using frameworks, etc.? Much more detailed information will be needed to properly answer this question.

Comment: a programming language and snippet with what you tried so far might help to get an answer here.

Comment: I'm using objective c with xcode and interface builder. I'm new to programming so I appreciate the help. We are doing a window based application and are using avfoundation frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a structure that captures all of the information you want to record about one sound in a track.  Like volume, length, pitch, which beat you're on, etc.

A track consists of a whole bunch of these sounds.

Then playing back the song involves processing all of the structure records that you recorded.